# Julia, how to install from a tar.gz?

Tags: julia

how to install julia from a .tar.gz? I want to install the latest version from here https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/releases/tag/v1.9.0-beta4

Comment: https://julialang.org/downloads/platform/#linux_and_freebsd

Comment: The explanation on the website is not detailed enough for my expertise, can you explain it further?

Answer (score 2):

run:

```
wget https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.9/julia-1.9.0-beta4-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
tar zxvf julia-1.9.0-beta4-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
```

and you have Julia installed. The path to Julia executable is `julia-1.9.0-beta4/bin/julia` relative to the directory where you downloaded the .tar.gz file.

Comment: thank! and what do you do with that executable?

Comment: you run it to start Julia. to run an executable go to the `julia-1.9.0-beta4/bin/` folder and write `./julia`.

Comment: Thanks! how do you configure your bash so that it runs julia-1.9..0-beta4 without having to go to that folder? that is, to run `julia` in whatever folder you are at the moment

Comment: As is explained in the link I originally provided you add `export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/<Julia directory>/bin"` to your .bashrc file. There are also other options, but this one is probably simplest.